# Combinations of colored objects

Tags: combinatorics

There are $ 25 $ balls in a box. Some balls are red and the rest are blue. We select $ 2 $ balls in a row, one after the other. The selection happens without repositioning. We are given that the probability of choosing $ 2 $ same colored balls is equal to the probability of choosing $ 2 $ different colored balls. How many red balls are in the box?

I would appreciate your guidance. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Expand both sides, then it's quadratic

Comment: Thank you very much, I solved it! You helped me a lot!!